# Filter a Realm database by matching on tags

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm Swift. I have a database full of `Document` objects, each of which has a `List` of `Tag` objects stored as a property. Given one or more tags, how can I get the set of `Document` objects that match?

My first thought was to filter with an NSPredicate `SUBQUERY`, but it appears [that isn't supported yet](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1490).

I also figured I could maintain a list on each `Tag` object of all of the `Document` objects that have been labelled with it, and then join the lists of each selected `Tag`. But I don't see a way to do that in Realm either.

Answer (score 2):

Your realm model should be like this,

```
class Document:Object{
    let tags = List<Tag>()
    //...
}
```

and then you can filter documents by tag using `ANY` keyword,

```
let realm = Realm()
var documentsFilteredByTag = realm.objects(Document).filter("ANY tags.id = '\(tagID)'")
```

Comment: How does this handle the case of multiple tags?